# Why does roboearth database search triger exception?

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the RoboEarth API through their website http://api.roboearth.org but it seems to be down for more than 2 weeks now.
This problem already appeared in the past. (http://answers.ros.org/question/147006/roboearth-dbexception-api/) But seems like nobody knew what's the problem or who to contact so I'm asking again.

```
DBException at /objects/result

'Hbase connection failed: Could not connect to pcube:9090'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://api.roboearth.org/objects/result?csrfmiddlewaretoken=144d3ff07953f78d9e7c00bd3912e748&query=cup&format=html
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206070/why-does-roboearth-database-search-triger-exception?/) by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The RoboEarth project has ended and support for the servers is running out. They are kept alive (i.e. connected to electricity), but no maintenance can be guaranteed. One alternative could be to install your own server according to the documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/re_platform), though I do not know how easy that is.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1